# Scheduled task and printer

Tags: batch-file, printing, cmd, task

i want to watch a folder on my Win7 64bit Machine for new pdf files - and print them autmatically when there is a pdf file in the folder. After printing, the pdf file should be moved in a subfolder. So, after some google research i did a small batch file.

```
cd "D:\print"
for %%i in (*.pdf) do (
"C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" /print "%%i" 
timeout /T 10 /nobreak
move D:\print\*.pdf D:\print\printed
echo %%i
)
```

I stored this in folder d:\print as print.cmd . When i start the cmd by doubleclick, my printer starts working and the pdf file moves to the subfolder i defined (D:\print\printed).

To watch the folder, i had the idea to create a sheduled task that repeat this cmd-script all 5 minutes.

BUT:
This dont work, when the script is started via scheduled tasks, the printer is not working - the "movement" of the file instead, is working.

I entered in the scheduled task:

Program: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe

Argument: /c"d:\print\print.cmd"

Any idea, why i cant acces the printer via the scheduled task? 
The printer is connected via usb.

Hope i could provide necessary information! Thanks for your answers!

Comment: The `move D:\print\*.pdf D:\print\printed` should be `move D:\print\%%i D:\print\printed` otherwise *all* of the `pdf`s will be moved after only one has been printed. Can't say I'm an expert on scheduled tasks, but it would appear to me that the default printer defined under the user that the scheduled task runs under isn't the required usb printer. Can you explicitly nominate a printer in the `PDFXCview.exe` arguments?

Comment: Did you chose a start in folder?  You are starting cmd.exe which makes the working directory the system32 directory which is on the C: drive.  So when you do a change directory you have to use the /D option to make the working directory the D: drive.  When you double click the batch file to run it the working directory is the D: drive because that is where the script is stored and executing from.

Comment: Wow! i ve added d:\print as the working directory in my task and it worked instantly! Thanks so much! I now need to do some tests and checks and hope i can ask you guys again to help me to improve the script ;)

Comment: If the batch file is sat in D:\Print, you could just add `PushD %~dp0` to force D:\Print to be the working directory too.

Answer (score 2):

1. Change this line: `move D:\print\*.pdf` to `move /Y D:\print\%%i`
2. Point the scheduled task to actually start your batch file instead of calling cmd and putting the path to your script in the arguments.

You could also edit the batch file and code it to loop every 5 minutes so you only have to start it once:

```
    PushD %~dp0    
    :start
    for %%i in ("D:\print\*.pdf") do (
    "C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" /print "%%i" 
    move /y "%%i" "D:\print\printed"
    echo %%i
    )
    timeout /T 300 /nobreak
    goto start
```

Comment: %%i is the whole path to the file so the move command can just be. `move /y "%%i" "D:\print\printed"`

Comment: Tried it. When there are 3 files in folder, it prints first file and move it, then it prints second file and move it, and so on. works quite fine. 

What is better, to make a task that works every 5 Minutes or to work with the t 300 and goto start. Then i have to start the task only at PC startup, what would you advice me? 

Is there any option to keep the CMD windows minimized or hide it when it works?

Comment: Either really. I guess the task running every five minutes will provide some redundancy so if the cmd window fails, the task will restart it every five minutes rather than waiting for someone to log off and back on. Set the scheduled task to run using the system account so that it's not visible to the logged on user.